# Convert a file from to Base 64 using JavaScript and converting it back to file using C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to convert pdf and image files to base 64 using javascript and convert it back to file using C# in WEB API.

Javascript

```
var filesSelected = document.getElementById("inputFileToLoad").files;
if (filesSelected.length > 0)
{
    var fileToLoad = filesSelected[0];
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) 
    {
        var textAreaFileContents = document.getElementById("textAreaFileContents");
        textAreaFileContents.innerHTML = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
    };
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
}
```

C#

```
Byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(dd[0].Image_base64Url);
File.WriteAllBytes(actualSavePath,bytes);
```

But in API I'm getting exception as `{"The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters. "}`

Please tell me how to proceed with this...
Thanks

Comment: what you you posting the api? it should be `fileReader.result`

Comment: Yes I am posting fileReader.result...

Comment: can you post the controller api action? what's the value being posted as `dd[0].Image_base64Url`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MDN: FileReader.readAsDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) those generated URLs are prefixed with something like `data:image/jpeg;base64,`. Have a look at your generated string. Look for the occurence of `base64,` and take the base64 data that starts after this prefix.

Comment: Removing data:image/jpeg;base64, worked. And if anyone faces the same issue,use this script to remove the prefix from URL...                                 
 var base64result = reader.result.split(',')[1];

Comment: While trying to upload bigger files say in 5MB, the scripts runs without converting the file to byte..Resulting in null error in API... Any fix for this??

Comment: @Hem I've converted a 11mb image to an base64 string using the MDN live-result, extracted the generated url from the firefox, dumped the data into a file, read this file in C# to decode the base64 data and writing out the image. that works. So it might be a browser dependend setting or an addon or something like that. And what do you mean by "runs without converting"? Is the `load` event fired? The `FileReader` also has an `progress` and an `error` event...

Answer (score 1):

Because the `FileReader.readAsDataURL()` produces a string that is prefixed with extra metadata (the "URL" portion), you need to strip it off on the C# side. Here's some sample code:

```
// Sample string from FileReader.readAsDataURL()
var base64 = "data:image/jpeg;base64,ba9867b6a86ba86b6a6ab6abaa====";

// Some known piece of information that will be in the above string
const string identifier = ";base64,";

// Find where it exists in the input string
var dataIndex = base64.IndexOf(identifier);

// Take the portion after this identifier; that's the real base-64 portion
var cleaned = base64.Substring(dataIndex + identifier.Length);

// Get the bytes
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cleaned);
```

You could condense this down if it's too verbose, I just wanted to explain it step by step.

```
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64.Substring(base64.IndexOf(";base64,") + 8));
```